# MapKit in iOS 6 - How to Find Places Nearby...?

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit, ios6

Using MapKit in iOS 6, how am I'm supposed to get nearby locations without having their specific coordinates? I'm also unsure if it's still possible...err...*allowed*...to use Google Maps API to accomplish this goal, as this is the only way I can think of to do this. 
I know everything is still in beta, but I've still found no information anywhere about this topic, on forums, in Apple's new MapKit Documentation, anywhere. All I want to do is perform a search for locations (let's say, parks, for example) within 'x' miles of the user's location.

It seems that since Apple has developed their own Maps application, they should have a way to accomplish this using MapKit or Core Location...right?

Comment: Sorry but this cant be discussed on SO. Its NDA. Try the Apple Dev Forums. The Apple Engineers hang out there sometimes.

Comment: Check out the WWDC 2012 videos - there might be something there.  They did demo something similar but I can't remember the details.  Apologies.

Comment: It's not NDA anymore, 6.1 contains the actual code, but there is still next to no documentation. I don't know what is happening at Apple, they used to be the best at documenting things, now they are becoming just another 'explanations are a hassle' also ran...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this code. This may help to you.

```
URLManager *urlmanager = [[URLManager alloc] init];
        urlmanager.delegate = self;
        urlmanager.responseType = JSON_TYPE;
        urlmanager.commandName = @"Search";

NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f",latitude,longitude];
//Location where you want to search

NSString *key = @"AIzaSyCNRpero6aM451X0IfgFHAd-Y3eJUssqoa8`enter code here`0E";
//This is the secret key which you will get from the Google API Console when you register your app.

NSString *radiuos = @"15000";
//This is the area within which you want to search
NSString *keyword = @"Hotel";//Search keyword you want to search

NSMutableDictionary *arguments = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; // zero argument

[arguments setValue:key forKey:@"key"];

[arguments setValue:locationString forKey:@"location"];

[arguments setValue:radiuos forKey:@"radius"];

[arguments setValue:@"true" forKey:@"sensor"];

[arguments setValue:keyword forKey:@"keyword"];

NSLog(@"Arguments are %@",arguments);

[urlmanager urlCallGetMethod:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json"] withParameters:arguments];
```